# Download JSON Blobs and convert to objects from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I've been trying to figure out the fastest way to connect to an Azure Storage account, cycle through a number of containers and convert the blobs inside containers into objects. All elements in the container are JSON and match different objects.

The structure as seen on Azure Storage Explorer would be:

```
Azure_Subscription
  |--Storage_Accounts
    |--My_Storage_Account
      |--blob1
      |--blob2
      |--blob3
      etc
```

Now based on what I've read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet) in the official documentation, to access and Download each blob and convert it so that it can be handled as JSON and deserialized, I would need to do all the below (assuming I don't have a list of blob URIs).

```cs
string testConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=;AccountKey=;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

// the service clients allow working at the Azure Storage level with Tables and Blobs
TableServiceClient tableServiceClient = new TableServiceClient(testConnectionString);
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(testConnectionString);
List<blob1> blob1List = new List<blob1>;

// this gives me a list of blob containers and I can programmatically retrieve
// the name of each individual container.
Pageable<BlobContainerItem> blobContainers = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainers();

// each BlobContainerItem represents an individual blob container (bill, building...)
foreach (BlobContainerItem blobContainerItem in blobContainers)
{
  // create a ContainerClient to make calls to each individual container
  BlobContainerClient clientForIndividualContainer =
    blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainerItem.Name);
  if (blobItem.Name.Equals("blob1"))
  {
    Pageable<BlobItem> blobItemList = clientForIndividualContainer.GetBlobs();
    foreach (BlobItem bi in blobItemList)
    {
      BlobClient blobClient = clientForIndividualContainer.GetBlobClient(bi.Name);
      var blobContent = blobClient.Download();
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(blobContent.Value.Content);
      string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
      blob1List.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<blob1>(text));
    }
  }
}
```

The project is targeting .net 5.0 and I will need to do something similar with Azure Tables as well. The goal is that I want to go through all blobs inside a number of containers (all of them JSON really) and compare them to all the blobs inside another storage account. I'm also open to any ideas on doing this differently altogether, but the purpose of this is to compare input into Azure Storage blobs and make sure that a new process uploads the same object structures. So for all `blob1` items in the Azure Storage account I compare these to a list of all the `oldBlob1` items in another storage account and check to see if they are all equal.

I hope the question makes sense... At this point the above code works and I can move the functionality inside the `if-else` into a method and instead of the `if-else` statement use a `switch`, but my main question is around reaching this point entirely. Without a massive list of blob URIs, do I need to make a `BlobServiceClient` to be able to make a list of `BlobContainerItem`(s) to then cycle through each of the containers and create for all of them `BlobContainerClient`(s) and then create a `BlobClient` for every single blob in the storage account to finally be able to get to the `Content` of the blob?

This seems like a lot of work to just get access to an individual file.

Comment: You could use the container to backend a static file web server and pull the content down using simple HTTP requests.  How would you LIKE to access them exactly?

Comment: I would want to load up each blob inside each container into its corresponding objects with the lowest amount of code/logic complexity, run my comparisons and save the output of the comparisons. My questions were centered around the fact that as far as I see it, there are around 3 layers of abstraction until I am doing the calls and it's quite obscure from my point of view. So really, I'm looking for the simplest/cleanest way to achieve this goal (which I have, it just seems unwieldy that's all.

Comment: There are ways to map azure storage as a drive letter on your local computer. You would then be able to more simply access those objects like a local filesystem, deserialize their contents and do what you need to.